# Response Body is empty in Express/Node JS Jest testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jestjs, supertest

I have recently started working on a Node js project and wrote some APIs. I am writing the test cases for one of the POST request but response body is empty.
Here's the code -

```
'use strict'

jest.mock('../../utils/db2.js')
const request = require('supertest')
const executeDb2Query = require('../../utils/db2.js')
const app = require('../../app')

describe('service read API test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
  })
  
  it('check Details Good', async () => {
    executeDb2Query.mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve([
        {
          dnum: '090703',
          num: 1,
          startdate: '2021-06-01',
          enddate: '2022-05-31',
          rolecode: 5,
          fnum: 1.049,
          lastmodifieddate: '2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279',
          createtime: '2021-06-01 10:53:24.269686'
        }
      ])
    )
    await request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/abc/xyz')
      .send({
        id: '090703'
      })
      // .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('Response Body :', JSON.stringify(res.body, null, 2))
        expect(res.body).toEqual({
          dnum: '090703',
          num: 1,
          startdate: '2021-06-01',
          enddate: '2022-05-31',
          rolecode: 5,
          fnum: 1.049,
          lastmodifieddate: '2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279',
          createtime: '2021-06-01 10:53:24.269686'
   
      })
  })
})
```

Above is my code and I am getting below response as the output as the test is failing -

```
 ● service read API test › check Details Good

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 8
    + Received  +  1

      Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "createtime": "2021-06-01 10:53:24.269686",
    -     "dnum": "090703",
    -     "enddate": "2022-05-31",
    -     "fnum": 1.049,
    -     "num": 1,
    -     "lastmodifieddate": "2021-06-02 05:34:04.382279",
    -     "rolecode": 5,
    -     "startdate": "2021-06-01",
    -   },
    +   Object {},
      ]

      84 |       .then(res => {
      85 |         console.log('Response Body :', JSON.stringify(res.body, null, 2))
    > 86 |         expect(res.body).toEqual([
         |                          ^
      87 |           {
      88 |             dnum: '090703',
      89 |             num: 1,

      at __tests__/routes/details.test.js:86:26
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/routes/details.test.js:76:5)

  console.log
    Response Body : [
      {}
    ]
```

Controller class code -

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { getDBDetails } = require('../utils/constants')
const executeDb2Query = require('../utils/db2')

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send('Request Body is empty. Please check!!')
    }
    const request= req.body
    const getDetails = await executeDb2Query({
      sql: getDBDetails(request),
      log: req.log,
      name: 'Get Details',
      errorMsg: 'Get error while getting the Details '
    })

    
      return res.status(200).json(getDetails)
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'No Records found for the given attributes' })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
})
```

Any suggestion what exactly I am doing wrong here? The response body is coming as empty when it should be matching to what I have in Promise resolve.

Comment: can you try changing the order of the mock and the require? That might help.

Comment: Getting the same error even after changing the order.

Comment: `const executeDb2Query = require('../utils/db2')` `jest.mock('../../utils/db2.js')` Those two paths look different. I am pretty sure there should be the same. There is something wrong with your mocks but not really easy to track down.

Comment: It looks to be same in the test file no? In the controller code, it's a bit different because the files are added such

Comment: @QuickLearner Did you ever figure out the answer to this?  My unit tests are exhibiting the same behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey - sorry for the late reply - I ended up using mockReturnValue which mimics the result which would be sent from the database.